# How can I setup internet fail-over using windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, failover

I would like to have fail-over internet on my Windows 10 Desktop PC. SO I have a Fritz!box 6490 cable and a Teltonika RUT240 LTE router, with a Win10 PC connected to the Fritz!box using a LAN cable and to the LTE router with a simple WLAN USB stick. When my cable internet fails, I would like my Desktop to use the internet over my LTW router. But currently I have to **disable** my LAN Adapter to use the internet from the LTE router.

My question is, is there a way to have the fail-over without the need to disable my LAN adapter?

PS: I also have all the virtual network cards from Hyper-V which may complicate things, but they shouldn't.

- The LAN Adapter is set to DHCP:

  ```
  IPv4-Adresse:     192.168.178.92
  Subnetzmaske:     255.255.255.0
  Standardgateway:  192.168.178.1
  ```
- The WLAN Adapter is set to DHCP:

  ```
  IPv4-Adresse:     192.168.1.2
  Subnetzmaske:     255.255.255.0
  Standardgateway:  192.168.1.1
  ```

How do I need to configure my network adapters so I don't have to disable my LAN adapter, when my LAN internet fails, to be able to continue to surf over LTE?

Comment: Windows 10 can have two adapters enabled at the same time, so no problem in having an automatic failover. Why is the WLAN set to a static address?

Comment: When two or more adapters are connected to, Windows will take several seconds to switch connections once one no longer has internet - does it not do so at all or takes longer than 60s?

Comment: I will test again and report back. Thank you for your comment!